# Detect onload/onerror for async scripts

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

Given something like the following code, is there any way to determine (from within an asynchronous callback) whether or not a particular script has finished loading.

```
<script async id="js" src="//example.com/my-script.js"></script>
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    var js = document.getElementById('js');
    js.onload = function() {
      console.log('loaded!');
    }
    js.onerror = function() {
      console.log('error!');
    }
  }, 0);
</script>
```

In the above code, the `onload`/`onerror` callbacks do not fire when the script is cached, but they do when it's not cached.

Can anyone think of a way to determine whether or not a particular script has finished loading (or an error occurred while loading) in cases like this? Basically I'm looking for a foolproof way to add load and/or error callbacks even in cases where the loading (or erroring) has already happened.

**NOTE:** I know there are many way to do this fully in JavaScript. For the purposes of this question, assume I cannot change the script tag, where it appears in the source, or its contents. I want to know if this is possible given an existing `<script async>` tag pointing to a third party resource.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue is exactly what you observed. When the script is cached, it is loaded before you even bound the events on. So your event handlers was never triggered. What you can try is to create script element in javascript, set the onload and onerror handlers, then set the source and insert into the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a recursive function and sessionStorage or localStorage :

in the script you load, declare this at the very end : 
`localStorage.myScriptIsLoaded=true`

then use a recursive function :

```
function recursive(){
   if(!localStorage.myScriptIsLoaded){
      setTimeout(recursive(),10);
   }
   else{
   //do what you want to do
   }
} 
recursive();
```